# Is there a fast way (keyboard shortcut, etc...) to auto adjust button size to match image size using storyboards?

Tags: ios

When I add an image to a button, I often have to look back at the image to get the widht and height, then back to interface builder and set the button width and height to match the image.

Is there a key shortcut or something that will set the width and height of the button automatically to match that of the image?

This question is regarding storyboards in xcode specifically.

Im aware that it can be done in code, not asking about that...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Interface Builder use menu Editor/Size To Fit Content.  Shortcut Cmd+=.

You need the button selected. If that option is greyed out, deselect, and reselect the button again.

Comment: Does anyone know a shortcut to reselect the element when it turns gray? Example: Select a button make a width change, the button is now grayed out on the left hence update constrains shortcut will not work. I have to re-select the button to perform an update constraint. Anyway around this?

Comment: For me this feature just works SOMETIMES... even reselecting the button in the left pane. Buggy?

Comment: This feature doesn't seem to like buttons in `UIStackViews`